# NSDictionary using contentsOfFile method doesn't build in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, plist

I am building a dictionary using the contentsOfFile method, and pointing the method to a plist.  My code is as follows:

```
func buildGraphicsDictionary() {

    var theme: String = "defaultTheme"

    var myDict: NSDictionary?

    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(theme, ofType: "plist") {
        println("path: \(path)")
        myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        println("dict count: \(myDict?.count)")
    } else {
        println("could not find plist file")
    }

}
```

The plist is found.  I know this for certain because I am able to print out the path and because when I change the name of the plist string to one that doesn't exist I get an error.  So I am confident the problem is not in accessing the plist.

However, when I attempt to print the number of elements in the dictionary using count, the console reports that the myDict has a value of nil.  So this tells me that the problem is actually in the method by which I am building the dictionary (contentsOfFile).  What is confusing is that I have seen other SO articles in which the same code is used (ostensibly) successfully.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Comment: Try printing the keys count of the NSDictionary or try printing the NSDictionary directly rather than the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code and it works perfectly.

Maybe the problem in plist?

I tested your code with this plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>test1</key>
    <string>one</string>
    <key>test2</key>
    <string>two</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And in my console I see:

```
dict count: Optional(2)
```

The plist must be located here

[image: Plist place]

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I do believe your answer has given me a clue.  The fact that your plist was working and mine not prompted me to examine the plist more closely and what I discovered is that my plist converter (soma app I downloaded), instead of creating a single dictionary of key value pairs was creating a single array of dictionaries!

Comment: That's good! If my response was helpful, you can mark it as answer and push the up vote button, I hope :)

Comment: Yes indeed.  I marked your answer as correct just now, and up voted it thank you.  It is worth noting that the plist may be located where you indicated, or in a "folder" grouped together with other plists.

Comment: To be clear: my problem was not the code snippet above, but rather a malformed plist.  Once my buddy provided a better csv to plist converter all was well. Thanks again.